Exponentiating the singular values of a matrix without explicitly computing them
Let $X = U\Sigma V$ be a singular value decomposition of a real matrix $X$.
It is possible to "cube" the singular values of $X$ (that is to compute $X_3$ = $U\Sigma_3V$ where $\Sigma_3$ has the same shape as $\Sigma$ and all its entries correspond to the cubed entries of $\Sigma$) and without explicitly computing the SVD of $X$, by realizing that $X_3 = XX^TX$.
A similar process can be applied to exponentiate the singular values of $X$ to any odd integer, for example $X_5 = XX^TXX^TX$.
Is there a way to also exponentiate the singular values of $X$ to even integers, without an explicit computation of its singular values decomposition?

Clearly, $U\Sigma_2V = U \Sigma V V^T \Sigma V = X (X^TX)^{1/2}$. Alternatively, $U\Sigma_2V = (XX^T)^{1/2} X$. I don't think this can be simplified further (e.g. to a polynomial in $X$ and $X^T$).
